# PL/SQL XML to Object Type with Attributes and text()

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I want to deserialize the following XML structure into an PL/SQL Object Type:

```
<ProcessingInfo>
     <MrwNumber>000001</MrwNumber>
     <Station SerialNumber="nice-Attribute">Hello</Station>
</ProcessingInfo>
```

What is special in this XML: The element `<Station>` has an attribute `SerialNumber` and the actual text() value `Hello`.

How do the types must be defined to deserialize the XML into a object types?

For the XML structure I have defined the following types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE station_t FORCE AS OBJECT (
     "@SerialNumber"   VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE processingInfo_t FORCE AS OBJECT (
     "MrwNumber"                  VARCHAR2(255)
   , "Station"                    station_t
);
```

This is my execution logic:

```
DECLARE
        l_obj processingInfo_t;
        l_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
        l_xml :=  xmltype(
        '<ProcessingInfo>
            <MrwNumber>000001</MrwNumber>
            <Station SerialNumber="nice-Attribute">Hello</Station>
        </ProcessingInfo>');

        l_xml.toObject(l_obj);
END;
```

And the error:

```
ORA-19031: XML element or attribute text does not match any in type DEMOGRAPHIC.STATION_T
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 196
ORA-06512: at line 11
19031. 00000 -  "XML element or attribute %s does not match any in type %s.%s"
*Cause:    The passed in XML tag does not match any in the object type
*Action:   Pass a valid canonical XML that can map to the given object type
```

I know that there is something missing in the `station_t`object, since the actual text() will be provided but it is not defined in the type. But I do figure it out.

Another question is, how can I access the attribute value when the serialization happend successfully on object level?

Additional: When I remove the text() = *Hello* from `<Station>`, the serialization seems to work:

```
DECLARE
        l_obj processingInfo_t;
        l_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
        l_xml :=  xmltype(
        '<ProcessingInfo>
            <MrwNumber>000001</MrwNumber>
            <Station SerialNumber="nice-Attribute"></Station>
        </ProcessingInfo>');

        l_xml.toObject(l_obj);
END;
```

Comment: Ok to access the attribute `SerialNumber` working with the following call:


        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_obj."MrwNumber");
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_obj."Station"."@SerialNumber");